# URLLib3 Connection Pool creates only one pool

Tags: python, connection-pooling, urllib3

Currently i'm trying to scrape a site but the site didn't allow more than 100 request for one tcp connection. So, i tried to create multiple connection pool for requests. I tried the following code. Shouldn't it create 15 connection pool?

```
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool
for i in range(15):
    pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=15)
    for j in range(15):
        resp= pool.request('GET', '/ajax/services/search/web')
    pool.num_connections
```

pool.num_connection always print 1

Comment: Your code makes multiple requests not connections, which is still what you're trying to avoid.  Print the value of `pool.num_requests` to see what I mean.

Comment: @BlackVegetable what i'm trying to do is create multiple tcp connection for same host. Any example would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the requests are made synchronously one after the other.
For this reason the pool will always use the same connection with no need to create any others.

Now let's say we run the code using threads, multiple requests will be issued concurrently.
In this case `pool.num_connections` will be greater than 1:

```py
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool


pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=15)

def send_request(_):
    pool.request('GET', '/ajax/services/search/web')
    print(pool.num_connections)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.map(send_request, range(5))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to close sockets every 100 requests, then you'll need to do that manually. Here's an example which closes all sockets every 5 requests:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.add_stderr_logger() # This lets you see when new connections are made

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
for j in range(15):
    resp = http.request('GET', url)
    if j % 5 == 0:
        # Reset the PoolManager's connections.
        # This might be overkill if you need more granular control per-host.
        http.clear()
```

You could do something similar using `HTTPConnectionPool` and doing `.close()` on it before replacing it with a fresh one. I prefer to use PoolManager when possible (there is generally no downside).

If you'd like to get super granular with connections, you can manually take connections out of an `HTTPConnectionPool` using `pool._get_conn()` and `.close()`'ing it.

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple tcp connections at the same time for one particular server from one client. any information regarding this would be very helpful for me. @shazow

Comment: Do you mean asynchronously? If so, then you'll need to use some currency primitives like threads or gevent. Specifying maxsize as you did in your question will allocate that many possible sockets in the pool.